# Is there a way to completely ignore a property using FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

When I try to bind a string ("1,000.00") to a decimal property (x) FluentValidation throws the following error: "The value '1,000.00' is not valid for x." I have a `DecimalModelBinder` that will handle binding the model but FluentValidation prevents me from getting that far.  I could strip the comma before the form is submitted but I would rather not handle this for many different fields.  I am looking for a way to tell FluentValidation to completely ignore the property and just trust me :).

Thanks in advance for any thoughts or suggestions!

Comment: is this a localization issue or are you forcing the non decimal format for some reason? i.e. what is the source of that string "1,000.00"

Comment: The source of the string is a textbox that requires the format #,###.00

Comment: by definition, the model binder converts strings (like from your form post) to 'models', in this case, the C# decimal type. So @amir-gh is correct. Also, the error message is a MVC binder one, not FV.

Answer (score 2):

i believe this error does not come from fluentValidaton this error probably generated by MVC modelBinding if your are using MVC as i know fluent validation validating object and you can not create instance of your object and assign string to decimal type. so you should search for problem on  your DecimalModelBinder